# Android SMS App Unexpectedly calling Default "New Message" Layout from Messaging App when Button is clicked

Tags: java, android, xml, sms, android-activity

Making a SMS App and it is going well so far, but ran into a problem last night after trying to implement a new activity.

When I click the "Send" Button on my Layout, it sends the SMS, and triggers a Toast notifying me of the Sent SMS.  This was working perfectly until I tried to add a onClick attribute to the  XML leading to an intent to start the new activity... That's when this started happening:

Instead of starting up the new activity I created, it sent me to the "New Message" Layout/Activity of the Default "Messaging" app included with the phone.  I did not understand this, so took away (unless I've missed something over and over) everything that I changed from when it was working.

YET: It is still sending me to that New Message activity when I click this button...

Can someone please tell me where in my code I am telling the application to start that activity?  Thank you!

TextActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TextActivity extends Activity {

Button buttonSend;
EditText textPhoneNo;
EditText textSMS;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.text_field);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSendText);
    textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNumber);
    textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTypeMessage);

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
            String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sendIntent.putExtra("SMS Body", sms);
            sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            startActivity(sendIntent);

            try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS failed, please try again later!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

// STARTING The Contact Selection Process
private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;

// References the Select Contact Button with onClick="clickHandle"
public void clickHandle(View view) {
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
}

// Interpreting the results from the Contact_picker
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
            Cursor cursor = null;
            String phone = "";
            String name = "";
            try {
                Uri result = data.getData();

                // get the contact id from the Uri
                String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                // query for everything phone
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                        null);

                int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
                int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

                // let's just get the first phone
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    phone = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                    name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);

                } else {

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                EditText phoneEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNumber);
                phoneEntry.setText(phone);

                TextView nameEntry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContactSelected);
                nameEntry.setText(name);

                if (phone.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No phone found for contact.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;
        }

    } else {

    }
}
}
```

My XML, text_field.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/burntorange" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSelectContact"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:onClick="clickHandle"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContactSelected"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="No Contact Selected"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPhoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Person&apos;s Phone Number"
    android:padding="10dp" >
</EditText>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@color/burntorange"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp" >

        <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/svEnterMessage"
            android:layout_width="269dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etTypeMessage"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/outline"
                android:hint="Type Message Here"
                android:minHeight="35dp"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" >"
            </EditText>
        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSendText"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone please tell me where in my code I am telling the application to start that activity?

This looks like it starts the default messaging app:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("SMS Body", sms);
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

If you don't want to load the default app, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Well, I guess I am using the default app, but before when I clicked send.. It used the app to send it but never actually brought me to the screen. It just sent it, said "SMS sent" and then that was it.  Can't figure out why it changed though. (Still new to this obviously :P)

Comment: Well, the code in the `try {}` block immediately after this looks like it should send the SMS. So my question is: why are you doing both? (Perhaps you just want to delete the `sendIntent` code?)

Comment: Oh my.... Yup. That was it. Just had to delete that. Must have added that Intent in there when experimenting around with it all. Should have been obvious haha. Well thanks a bunch Sam. I'm slowly getting better at all this.